# Relative clause where v.s which

Tags: relative-clauses

The restaurant (where/which) he has been to has been sold.

The amusement park (where/which) I like to go to is the most popular in the country.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

*Which* identifies the one being referred to. *Where* means the same as *at which* or *to which.*

"The amusement park *where I like to go* **or** *which I like to go to*"

However, you can't really say "The restaurant where he has been" because it sounds as though he has been staying there. You could say "where he has eaten" instead.